# Is it possible to detect the real IP from a modifed header

Tags: forensics

Is it possible to find the real IP from a header which seems to be changed in order to hide the sender's IP?

Comment: ANd what exactly do you call a header? Who are you as a recipient, where does the sender come from and where does the message transit?

Answer (score 1):

No, the IP header will have been modified to remove the sender's real IP.

If you believe the packet with the altered header originated within your network, you may be able to check network logs to find the origin of the packet.